is there any inequality concerning sum of maximal row/column/diagonal entries of an infinite matrix?
let $T$ be a bounded operator on $l^2\mathbb(Z)$ space viewed as an infinite matrix indexed by integer number, I want to compare $max\{\sum\limits_{x}\sup_{y}T(x,y)\},\sum\limits_{y}\sup_{x}T(x,y)\}$(or $l^p$ sum) and $\sum\limits_{z}\sup_{y-x=z}T(x,y)$, is there and inequality concern these terms? anything compare row vectors, column vectors, and diagonal vectors will be thankful.
